# Error Joining using same id for two columns - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

For some reason I can't get this join working. I'm looking for the results to be Song Title, Made Popular By, Recording Title, Recorded By.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Song.title AS `Song Title`, 
PerfArtist.name AS `Made Popular By`, 
Recording.title AS `Recording Title`, 
PerfArtist.name AS `Recorded By`
FROM PerfArtist_Recording
INNER JOIN Recording ON PerfArtist_Recording.Recording_id = Recording.id
INNER JOIN Song_Recording ON Song_Recording.Recording_id = Recording.id
INNER JOIN Song ON Song_Recording.Song_id = Song.id, 
INNER JOIN PerfArtist ON MadePopularBy.PerfArtist_id = PerfArtist_id
INNER JOIN PerfArtist ON PerfArtist_Recording.PerfArtist_id = PerfArtist.id
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN PerfArtist ON MadePopularBy.PerfArtist_id = PerfArtist_id
     INNER ' at line 9
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: which one is line 9, in terms of the error?

Comment: You have a comma in this line: `INNER JOIN Song ON Song_Recording.Song_id = Song.id,` - it shouldn't be there.

Comment: you need to qualify every field that has the same name as another field in a different table.  For example `INNER JOIN Recording ON PerfArtist_Recording.Recording_id = Recording.id` becomes `INNER JOIN Recording ON PerfArtist_Recording.Recording_id = Recording.Recording.id` - the only one where you do it is the join with Song.id

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej just reloaded and saw your comment as well, I'll vote you

Comment: Thanks @Przemyslaw Kruglej and but now I get this error: Not unique table/alias: 'PerfArtist'. I think this is the real error I'm trying to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Song.title AS 'Song Title', 
    PerfArtist1.`name` AS 'Made Popular By', 
    Recording.title AS 'Recording Title', 
    PerfArtist2.`name` AS 'Recorded By'
FROM 
    PerfArtist_Recording
INNER JOIN
    Recording ON PerfArtist_Recording.Recording_id = Recording.id
INNER JOIN 
    Song_Recording ON Song_Recording.Recording_id = Recording.id
INNER JOIN 
    Song ON Song_Recording.Song_id = Song.id 
INNER JOIN 
    PerfArtist perfArtist1 ON MadePopularBy.PerfArtist_id = perfArtist1.PerfArtist_id
INNER JOIN 
    PerfArtist perfArtist2 ON PerfArtist_Recording.PerfArtist_id = perfArtist2.PerfArtist.id
```

Removed a stray colon, replaced back ticks with single quotation marks to clarification with regards to column names and aliases.

Added aliases for PerfArtist

Comment: Thanks @Shamil. After replacing as you suggested I get the error "Not unique table/alias: 'PerfArtist'"

Comment: @dwags modified the SQL to use aliases, which should help you. I've given `PerfArtist` aliases `perfArtist1` and `perfArtist2`

Comment: I think we're close but its still not working. See PerfArtist is the name of the table that lists the primary key and the artist's name. Name is the column on that table (PerfArtist.name). I then have a MadePopularBy (which is basically a Song_PerfArtist pivot table) and a PerfArtist_Recording pivot table. The trouble I'm having is joining both pivot tables to the same PerfArtist table. With what you just gave me I'm getting this error message: Unknown column 'MadePopularBy.PerfArtist_id' in 'on clause' Thanks so much for the help! @Shamil

Comment: you got me on the right track. I just edited above to get it working. Thanks!